# How to display an image with use of jar file in Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, android-library

I am new for Android. I want to create an jar file if i call a method of that jar file in another android application it will show an image in imageview of the application. For example 
 a method in jar file as `DisplayImg(URL);` i will use this jar as library in another application and here i will create an imageview

```
ImageView imageView;
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
```

Then if i call `imageView.DisplayImg(URL);` then it will display specified url image on the imageview. I spend lot more time to get the solution but not work.plz help with the code thank

Comment: Check out my ans here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android/24134425#24134425

Comment: Thank for response but I want to write code to display image when call method in jar file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create a library, in fact, there is a same library available for doing **exactly** what you want to!
It's called `Picasso`. You can find it [here](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Also note that if you want `imageView.DisplayImage(URL);` you should create a new instance of `ImageView` class, because it doesn't contain this method. I recommend using `DisplayImage(URL, imageView);`.

But in case you **REALLY WANT** to do this, here you go:

1- For creating a library, create a `New Android Application Project`, and in the second window, check `Mark this project as a library` option. Also notice that we don't need `Activity`.

2- Create a new class, such as `ImageUtils.java` in the newly-created project. Here you need to put the `DisplayImage()` method:

```
    public static void DisplayImage(String URL, ImageView imageView) {
        new DownloadImageTask(imageView).execute(URL);
    }
```

And this for the `DownloadImageTask` class :

```
public static class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    ImageView imageView;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.imageView = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap imageBitmap = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Probably there's no Internet connection. Warn the user about checking his/her connection.
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return imageBitmap;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (imageView != null) imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

}
```

3- Execute your project as an android application.

4- There should be a `jar` file under the `bin` folder. It's your library. Import it to your other applications and use it. In that applications you can use it with this code:

```
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    ImageUtils.DisplayImage(URL, imageView);
```

5- Don't forget to add this permission to the apps that use this library:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**Hope it helps :)**